# Minko Engine - Cannot compile

Tags: c++, minko

Sorry to be such a noob, but this is my first time compiling anything and i seem to have to everything correct. First i downloaded github client, then i cloned the minko SDK, then i download visual studio, then i added the variable in my system for D:\Minko\minko , and then i loaded the solution file in visual studio clicked f7 i think it was and watched it build perfect without errors (before or after i had to run the .bat file, i dont reme,ber the exact order from tutorial). Problem is i do not see any executables for running the minko studio, and when i try to open a .cpp in code blocks i get an error for the header files as well as trying to open the .cpp file in visual studio i click build for one of the tutorial examples aand nothing happens.. Sorry again and thank you in advance. Will there be a .exe any time soon? Oh, i also installed enscriptem just fine in case it was required.

Comment: Someone might be able to help if you post error messages.

Comment: Yea.. there is no error, i just dont see what to do once i finish all the steps... No executables found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minko Studio is **not** part of the open source Minko SDK.

Minko Studio is actually deprecated. It might be soon replaced with a more efficient and powerful Blender plugin, but we have no release date yet.

Comment: Oh wow that actually sounds so awesome!!! I did notice that .blend files were supported and i was wondering how much information could be shared. I am currently learning c++ , will you be allowing people to openly develop with your team?

Comment: Sure. Feel free to contribute to the open source SDK on github.

Comment: Ok great, check out blend4web.com they also have an integrated plugin for web export. Maybe you guys can work together, your c++ integration can maybe get blenders logic bricks to work with web? I will be in contact via github soon, You guys are great!!!! Also contact blender, i know they are planning a BGE and BPY merge with the game engine for blender 3 so the minko engine can really be a part of bender you can get funded for developing open source and have a community of developers!!!

Comment: Minko already targets the web and much more : Windows, Linux, iOS, Android, OSX... So we don't really need blend4web.

Comment: I understand, as far as targeting platforms it seems almost everyone can (the web is a different category). You guys are planning a blender plugin, those guys are already prepared for node based programming for when blender makes the merge of the game engine into blender. So its not a matter of who needs who, its a matter of how you both can help each other. You have C++ and great compression, they have a tight integration with blender that will be a one click export from whats created in blender to the web.. Add Blender, B4W , Minko= Inside/out limitless product. World must work together.....

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place for this. Please continue the discussion here: https://github.com/aerys/minko/issues/220